# apostrophe-assets: Remove from asset chain

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to build an apostrophe module and publish it on npm. It will help to comply with European GDPR by temporarily remove js assets that set cookies (like Google Analytics) or send requests with "personal" – IP – information (like Google Fonts, yes that is strange).

The option to remove one script could look like this:

```
{
  path: '/path/to/script',
  type: 'tracking'
}
```

The safest way of doing it would be on the server by removing the scripts from the asset chain of `apostrophe-assets`, I think.

But I am stuck here. How could I remove specific scripts and add them again if the user allows those scripts?

Is this possible at the moment or do we need to enhance `apostrophe-assets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot make exceptions to the pushing of assets, except of course for the user vs. anon distinction, which avoids pushing tons of extra code to people who will not be editing with Apostrophe.

However, you'll note that the code we push to the browser consists almost entirely of libraries that don't do anything until invoked by javascript calls that are pushed there via apos.push.browserCall or req.browserCall.

That second method is very powerful because it means you can decide to make, or not make, a javascript call based on the value, for instance, of req.session or req.user.

So in short: you can push all that code to users who decline its use — as long as you don't invoke it. Defining a library is not the same thing as invoking each of its functions.